# php mysql date conversion decimal

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date.  The format is:

```
1298588277.0
```

Note the decimal.  This is from an xml feed so I cannot directly change the format.  I am led to believe the decimal will be used later once "time runs out" as we all know.

What is the best way to store this as a single column value in a mysql database?  What should I set the column as?

Comment: Why not using DECIMAL? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

Comment: I did not know a decimal type exists. Thanks and please delete this question.

Comment: You don't need to delete the question.  It can stay so that someone else who has this question in the future can find the answer.  You should revert the edit where you blanked it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you cannot use the `DECIMAL` column type?

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `fieldname` DECIMAL( 15, 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

**EDIT** Ahh... read the comments before answering, eh?  :embarrassed: